# How to get the content in quotes (without the quotes) using Regex?

Tags: regex

In this example, the selection includes the quotes.

```
"Foo Bar" "Another Value" something else "Suganthan"
```

Regex:

```
(\"[\w\s]+\")
```

Output:

```
"Foo Bar"
"Another Value"
"Suganthan"
```

I need to print only the content between them. Like this:

```
Foo Bar
Another Value
Suganthan
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/XuvZ1x/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a better regex for matching quoted words (i.e. the words that are between double-quotes) is probably:

```
\w+        # Match 1 or more word characters
(?:        # start of a non capturing group
    \s     # match a white-space character
    \w+    # match one more word characters
)*         # 0 or more times
```

But realize that `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-z0-9_]`. If you don't want to allow numerics and the underscore, then replace `\w` with `[a-zA-Z]`.

You did not specify what language you are using. If it supports variable-length look behinds, then you can use:

```
(?<=(?:^|\s)")(\w+(?:\s\w+)*)(?=")
```

The lookahead assertion, `(?=")`, requires that the quoted words be followed by a double quote.

The lookbehind assertion, `(?<=(?:^|\s)")` says that the previous quoted words must be preceded by either the start of the string followed by a double quote or a white space character followed by a double quote. The more obvious but less precise lookbehind assertion, `(?<=")`, which just requires that the quoted words be preceded by a double quote, when scanning:

```
"ABC"DEF"
```

would recognize both "ABC" and "DEF".

If you cannot use variable-length lookbehind assertions, then:

```
(?:(?:^"|\s"))(\w+(?:\s\w+)*)(?=")
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LcgvlX/2/)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use grouping you could use a positive look behind and ahead:

```
(?<=\")[\w][\w\s]+[\w](?=\")
```

https://regex101.com/r/kd8t19/1

It only captures strings that have their first 'word' character succeed a quote and their last 'word' character precede a quote.

`"a b c" match (a b c)`

`" a b c" no match`

`"a b c " no match`

`"a   b   c"  match (a   b   c)`